# I need to write a program that shall make a small number of mistakes every now and then.

Tags: math-software

For some reason, I need to have a program that will make a small no. of mistakes every now and then, and I should not know what mistakes it has made and when.

*I do not need it to make multiple mistakes in one set(run of the algorithm), but rather I plan on making (say) 10,000 runs of the program, and I need it to make mistakes 200 times ..*

Very importantly, I must be sanguine that there are no more than (1/5)n mistakes, where n is the total no. of results generated using the program.

The *results* that I am talking about here can be anything that is quantifiable and verifiable, like eg. an array of values.

Doing something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
   //one fifth of the times put garbage in the array using random function!!
   for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
      array[j]=j;
```

is too simplistic and not *real* enough.

So I thought may be I must look for a mathematical function that can do this for me. Any ideas ?

P.S. I am a noob at math (struggled with engineering college math). So please elaborate your answer. Dont say something like "Use XXX'YYY theorem .." I might not understand!
Also, plese attach proper taf to this question. I could not thing of any ..

Comment: What do you mean by *real* enough?  Maybe define a set of mistakes that you choose from-swap a pair of values in the array, change just one value in the array, change all the 0's in the array to 1's?

Comment: So, something like `if (rand() < 0.2) then`, then?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, cant use that. (I think this was clear enough from my code sample)

Comment: No, it wasn't; you haven't said anything about conditionals not being allowed.

Comment: Are @RYUZAKI and drunkMonk the same person?

Comment: @RahulNarain yeah! Actually the machines at the company i work for are firewalled for social networking and gmail, yahoo, etc; so i have two accounts.

Comment: @RYUZAKI: would you like the two accounts merged? The merged accounts _should_ (IIRC) keep both sets of log-in information, and you then should be able to log-in using an OpenID provider other than Facebook/Google etc.

Comment: @WillieWong it would be awesome if you could merge the accounts with the option of multiple login credentials. Thanks a lot. P.S. Just make sure you preserve the Stackexchange credentials of ritwik_ghosh@persistent.com so that i can use this id and password to log into this account. Also, would this work for all SE sites or just this one ?

Comment: @RYUZAKI I just did the merge. It should propagate across all SE sites in your network. The login credentials lists now both the ones you used for RYUZAKI and drunkMonk, so it *should* work. If it somehow *doesn't*, please send an e-mail to team@stackexchange.com linking to this discussion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a programming language will allow picking a (pseudo-)random item from a list. If you can the following pseudocode seems to do what you want:

1. BigList is the complete list of the number of runs, say 10000.
2. For $i$ = $1$ to $200$.
3. Pick $n$ from BigList. (This uses the item picking function)
4. Replace BigList with BigList $\smallsetminus \{ n \} $. (Delete $n$ from BigList)
5. End For  (At the end of the for loop we now know which runs should have an error.
6. Do $i$ = $1$ to $10000$.
7. If $i$ is still in BigList do the right thing, else do the wrong thing.
8. End Do.